# ADC "internal" overvoltage with gain, ADC overvoltage above Vref

Tags: adc, maximum-ratings

I want to ask about maximum input voltage for ADC in 2 cases

1. I'm using MCP3424, with internal differential amplifier (gain 2, 4 or 8). Reference is fixed 2048mV. What will happen, if I apply 2V to Vin+ and 0V to Vin- when gain 8 is used? **It will just saturate or it will be damaged?**
2. I'm PIC18F25F50 with ADC powered from 5V. I have positive Vref set to 1024mV, negative Vref to ground. Can it be damaged when I apply 4V to input?

In datasheets, in maximum ratings - maximum input voltage is usually Vdd + 0.3V. I know that at higher voltage ESD diodes current will flow. But what about internal circuits when internal amplifier is used, or when Vref is below input voltage?

Comment: The internal circuits can't generate voltages beyond the power rails, so they never generate voltages beyond the maximum ratings of the next stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it won't be damaged in either case - the Vref is "like" a voltage used on a comparator input - taking the other input higher does no damage to anything but your signal shape providing you don't exceed absolute maximum ratings for the device.